# Django 1.8 NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I get this error while trying to access posts in the index.html template:

> Reverse for 'single_post' with arguments '(5,)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$(?P[0-9]+)/$']

index.html template:

```
{% if hot_posts %}
<ul>
    {% for post in hot_posts %}
        {% if post.acceptable %}
        <li>
            <h2>
                <a href="{% url 'post:single_post' post.id %}/">{{post.title}}</a>
            </h2>
            <a href="{% url 'post:single_post' post.id %}/">
                <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="{{post.title}}"
                class="post-img" />
            </a>
            <p>امتیاز: <span>{{ post.likes }}</span></p>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No posts are avaialable.</p>
{% endif %}
```

post.views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    hot_posts = Post.objects.order_by('-likes')[:10]
    template = 'posts/index.html'
    context = {"hot_posts":hot_posts}

    return render(request, template, context)

def single_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    template = 'posts/single_post.html'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from post.admin import site_admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^modir/', include(site_admin.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('post.urls', namespace='post')),
]
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="home_page"),
    url(r'^mosama/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.single_post,
        name="single_post")
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the regex that includes the post urls.

```
url(r'^', include('post.urls', namespace='post')),
```

Comment: i want the homepage to show blog posts, and also single posts are accessible through "mosama/post_id/"

Comment: I didn't wanted posts to be available under '/mosama/' so i edited the urls.py to what is now and i guess it's doing the job

Comment: Yes, your updated url patterns look better. An alternative would be to move `views.index` into your project urls, then include the `post.urls` under `^mosama/`.